# typecasting int to byte throws error when done via constant instead of variable

Tags: c#

I'm struggling with the fact that typecasting an int bigger than a byte, to a byte works for a variable int, but not for a constant int.

Some examples that show both cases:

```
int j = 28;
(byte)((byte)j * 128)
```

This resulted in 0. Which is logical. 128 * 28 = 3584. Which is 0xE00, the first byte is 0.

```
const int p = 28;
(byte)((byte)p * 128)
```

> (2,1): error CS0221: Constant value '3584' cannot be converted to a 'byte' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)

Why is there an error thrown in case of a constant and not when a variable is used?

Comment: Compile time (latter) vs run time (former). If you change both of the code samples so that they compile, and then view the IL, you'll see why they act differently. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wl9po0 Compile time maths functions effectively as checked, while runtime defaults to unchecked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is explained in the following article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked

> By default, an expression that contains only constant values causes a compiler error if the expression produces a value that is outside the range of the destination type. If the expression contains one or more non-constant values, the compiler does not detect the overflow.

Presumably because if the value is not constant, it could be changed elsewhere in the code, and it would be difficult or impossible for all cases for the compiler to determine whether or not it would be valid at the point of the conversion. However, when constant, that problem does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!